# Multikeypress not working properly sing JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code can take Two input directly from browser window , if I press `q` the 4000 is incremented by 1 when pressing `w` the 3000 is incremented by 1, when both pressed both incremented.But
when I unpress one of them lets say `q` the `w`should kept working but doesn't, both stops.
Any solution!? is my logic wrong or keydown just works that way .tnx.

HTML:

```
<div id="num1">3000</div>
<div id="num2">4000</div>
<div >w =<span id="w"></span></div>
<div >q =<span id="q"></span></div>
<div>Last raised key=<span id="deleted"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    keylogger={};

    window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
        keylogger[e.key]=true;
        document.getElementById("w").innerHTML=keylogger['w'];
        document.getElementById("q").innerHTML=keylogger['q'];
        div1=document.getElementById("num1") ;
        div2=document.getElementById("num2") ;

        if(keylogger['w'] && keylogger['q']){
            value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
            div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
            value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
            div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
        }
        if(keylogger['w']){
            value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
            div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
        }
        if(keylogger['q']){

            value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
            div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
        document.getElementById("deleted").innerHTML=e.key;
        delete keylogger[e.key];
    })


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty solution:
Take this code and run it. It will work but you will need to clean it up. Reason to why your code is not working is because when you release one key (when two are pressed) then the event is aborted and that is why you cant proceed.

Tips for a better solution:
This solution works. It is not nice however. If you want to make it nicer you should
assign the setInterval function to a variable ad invoke it inside the addEventListener "keydown". In that place you should make sure to only initialize it once (check if it has been initialized before). If already initialized/running dont do anything.

Then on addEventListener "keyup" you should remove the variable function with clearInterval so that you dont have the setInterval running when its not needed.

Please note that in your case you will have two variables. w and q that you assign the setInterval function. Maybe in an array like you do with the keyLogger = {} / [].

Dirty code:

```
<html>
<head><title>2 key press</title></head>
<body>
<div id="num1">3000</div>
<div id="num2">4000</div>
<div >w =<span id="w"></span></div>
<div >q =<span id="q"></span></div>
<div>Last raised key=<span id="deleted"></span></div>
<script>
keylogger={};

window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    keylogger[e.key]=true;
    setKeyLogger();
});

window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    document.getElementById("deleted").innerHTML=e.key;
    delete keylogger[e.key];
    setKeyLogger();
})

function setKeyLogger() { 
    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML=keylogger['w'];
    document.getElementById("q").innerHTML=keylogger['q'];
}

setInterval(function(){
    div1=document.getElementById("num1") ;
    div2=document.getElementById("num2") ;

    if(keylogger['w'] && keylogger['q']){
        value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
        div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
        value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
        div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(keylogger['w']){
        value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
        div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(keylogger['q']){
        value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
        div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
    }
 }, 250);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx man this was the most usefull among all. if I change the time interval to like 5 millisecond works just like I wanted .

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in you `if else` condition. when you press both `w` and `q` together all conditions are `true`. so you must use `else`. change your js code with code below:

```
<script>
keylogger={};

window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    keylogger[e.key]=true;
    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML=keylogger['w'];
    document.getElementById("q").innerHTML=keylogger['q'];
    div1=document.getElementById("num1") ;
    div2=document.getElementById("num2") ;

    if(keylogger['w'] && keylogger['q']){
        value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
        div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
        value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
        div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(keylogger['w']){
        value=parseInt(div1.innerHTML);
        div1.innerHTML=++div1.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(keylogger['q']){

        value=parseInt(div2.innerHTML);
        div2.innerHTML=++div2.innerHTML;
    }
});
window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    document.getElementById("deleted").innerHTML=e.key;
    delete keylogger[e.key];
})


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of how the series of interrupts are handled by the Operating System.

**Try this:**

*Demo 1:*

1. Long press the key "q"
2. Long press the key "w"
3. Release the key "w"

*Demo 2:*

1. Long press the key "q"
2. Long press the key "w"
3. Release the key "q"

*Results:*
You'll notice that in the *Demo 1*, both counters stopped iterating **BUT** in the *Demo 2*, it's working fine.

My guess is, since the pressing and releasing of the keys, both send a separate interrupts to the processor, the chronological order matter here. The interrupt sent when the key is pressed must be expecting a release interrupt of the same key as well.

More on how the interrupts work here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97108/are-multiple-interrupts-generated-when-i-hold-down-a-key-on-my-keyboard

**This is just an attempt to initiate a path for possible solution for the problem. If I completely missed the point, at least, we can be sure that the above mentioned isn't the cause**